# skin and theme in asp.net issue

Tags: asp.net, themes, skin

I'm going to apply my skin to a webpage and I wrote in the skin file:

```
<input class="th1">
```

and the stylesheet file is this:

```
.th1{
border:dashed #00ff21 1px;
}
```

and I got this error at runtime:

```
Literal content "<input class='th1'>" is not allowed within a 'skin file'.
```

what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot skin HTML-Controls. Use an ASP.NET control instead, please.

Comment: As Alexander said I used css instead